# jqGrid default value does not work?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid, and one column should have a default value when adding a new row. I have followed the documentation, but the value never appears.

This is the column from the colModel:

```
{name: 'Lt', index: 'Lt', width: 25, editable: true, editoptions: {defaultValue: 'N'}}
```

And this is how I call addRowData:

```
$("#grid").addRowData(-1,
    { Datum: $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date()) }, "first", true)
```

As far as I can see, I'm doing it by the book!

Complete grid def:

```
    $("#dagbok_grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd',
            'e',
            'f',
            'g',
            'h',
            'i',
            'j',
            'k',
            'l',
            'm',
            'n',
            'o',
            'p',
            'q',
            'r',
            's'],
        colModel: [
          { name: 'a', index: 'a', width: 30, formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: 'checkbox', editable: true },
          { name: 'b', index: 'b', width: 30, formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: 'checkbox', editable: true },
          { name: 'c', index: 'c', width: 70, formatter: 'date', editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker(); } } },
          { name: 'd', index: 'd', width: 65, editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { srcformat: 'H:i:s', newformat: 'ShortTime' }, editrules: { time: true} },
          { name: 'e', index: 'e', width: 80, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'f', index: 'f', width: 100, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: {rows: '7'} },
          { name: 'g', index: 'g', width: 80, editable: true, edittype: 'textarea', editoptions: { rows: '7'} },
          { name: 'h', index: 'h', width: 80, editable: true, editrules: { maxValue: 50} },
          { name: 'i', index: 'i', width: 120, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'j', index: 'j', width: 200, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'k', index: 'k', width: 70, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'l', index: 'l', width: 70, editable: true, editrules: { maxValue: 10} },
          { name: 'm', index: 'm', width: 25, editable: true, editoptions: { defaultValue: 'N'} },
          { name: 'n', index: 'n', width: 70, editable: true, editrules: { integer: true, maxValue: 999999 }, formatter: formatPosition, unformat: unformatPosition },
          { name: 'o', index: 'o', width: 25, editable: true, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: chkLongitudTecken} },
          { name: 'p', index: 'p', width: 80, editable: true, editrules: { integer: true, maxValue: 999999 }, formatter: formatPosition, unformat: unformatPosition },
          { name: 'q', index: 'q', width: 80, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'r', index: 'r', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { maxValue: 50} },
          { name: 's', index: 's', width: 65, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
        ],
        sortname: 'c',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        onSelectRow: function (id) {
            if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                jQuery('#dagbok_grid').saveRow(lastsel);
                lastsel = id;
            }
            jQuery('#dagbok_grid').editRow(id, true);
        },
        height: 400,
        editurl: '@Url.Action("SaveGridRow")',
        caption: 'my grid'
    });
```

I also later on add select-values to some cols:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '@Url.Action("GetGridComboValues")',
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var grid = $("#dagbok_grid");
            grid.setColProp("e", { editoptions: { value: data.kallor} });
            grid.setColProp("i", { editoptions: { value: data.rubriker} });
            grid.setColProp("j", { editoptions: { value: data.verksamheter} });
            grid.setColProp("k", { editoptions: { value: data.opPadrag, dataEvents: [{ type: 'change', fn: function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetVerksamhetskod")',
                    data: { "opPadragId": e.currentTarget.value },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        var selr = jQuery('#dagbok_grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        jQuery("#dagbok_grid").jqGrid('setCell', selr, "l", data);
                    }
                });
            }
            }]
            }
            });
            grid.setColProp("q", { editoptions: { value: data.medier} });
            grid.setColProp("s", { editoptions: { value: data.regioner} });
        }
    });
```

Add and delete code

```
    $("#toolbarAddButton")
        .button()
        .click(function () {
            $("#dagbok_grid").addRowData(-1, { Datum: $.datepicker.formatDate("yy-mm-dd", new Date()) }, "first", true)
        });

    $("#toolbarDeleteButton").click(function () {
        var radid = $("#dagbok_grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow");
        if (radid != null) {
            var su = $("#dagbok_grid").jqGrid("delRowData", radid);
            $("#dagbok_grid").jqGrid("delGridRow", radid, { url: '@Url.Action("DeleteGridRow")', reloadaftersubmit: false });

        }
    })
```

Save executes when the user press entering while in edit mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you defined `editoptions: { defaultValue: 'N'}`. You can read in the documentation of the [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editoptions)

> The option can be string or function. This option is valid **only in
>   Form Editing module** when used with `editGridRow` method in add mode. If
>   defined the input element is set with this value if only element is
>   empty. If used in selects the text should be provided and not the key.
>   Also when a function is used the function should return value.

What you want is that default value will be set during *filling* the grid body and not during editing. For the purpose exist `defaulValue` formatter option, but it will be used only for some predefined formatters (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apredefined_formatter#predefined_format_types)).

You can solve the problem either by usage of [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_formatter) or, if you use `addRowData` method directly, by adding explicit the value of `Lt` column.

I don't recommend to use low-level method `addRowData` which is slow and will be mostly used in wrong way. You used for example `-1` as the rowid. If you would execute the same statement more as one time you will have id duplicates which is error and can follow to very strange effects. If you want that jqGrid generate the unique ids itself you should use `undefined` as the rowid parameter.

Comment: Thanks! What method do you recommend for adding a row if not addRowData? The purpose of -1 is that I know that it's a newly added row on the serverside. I might be able to use some flag for that instead.

I only need the default value when I add a new row, not when filling already existing rows.

Comment: @kaze: To get you the best recommendation about the usage of `addRowData` I need have more information about the grid which you use (the JavaScript code) and **the scenario** in which the row need be added. Mostly `data` parameters is the best way in case of usage `datatype: 'local'`. How I wrote in my answer I don't understand the problem of setting default value if you call `addRowData` explicitly. Why you not just add `Lt: 'N'` to the list of properties of row added by `addRowData`?

Comment: I'm using rowEditing, with an editUrl. I'm sending the updates to the server for saving. I also have a delete, which sends the id to a delete method on the server. When the user press a "new" button in a toolbar, I would like a new row to be inserted at the top for the user to enter values in. I will update my question with the acutal code.

Comment: @kaze: I would recommend you to use [addRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:inline_editing#addrow) method instead of `addRowData`. You can use `addRowParams: {oneditfunc: function() {/*you code here*/}}` to make some initialization actions after the empty row will be added and the inline editing of the new row will be started. Inside of `oneditfunc` you can make any initialization work. For simplest initialization actions you can use `dataInit`: `editoptions: {dataInit: function(elem) {/*your code here*/}}`.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, I will try it at once!